# jquery validation rules parameter from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

i have `current_stock` variable which is updated by ajax request everytime i clicked Edit button. after the ajax request success, it will popup a modal like this 
[image]

im using jQuery validation to validate the form. one of the rules is max.  im trying to set the max value equal to `current_stock` variable.
im trying this :

```
$("#form_detail").validate({
    rules: {
        jumlah: {
            required: true,
            number: true,
            max: current_stock
        }
    },
    messages: {
        jumlah: {
            required: "Jumlah tidak boleh kosong.",
            number: "Jumlah hanya dapat diisi dengan angka.",
            max: "Tidak bisa melebihi sisa Stok"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        save_edit();
    }
});
```

but it always says the `current_stock` variable is 0.
i tried to print the variable using the console, the variable value is right. but the value in the validation is always 0.
this is where i initialize the `current_stok` variable

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var base_url = "<?php echo base_url()?>";
        var current_stock = 0;
 </script>
```

this is the function that make an ajax request and popup the modal

```
    function edit_jumlah(id_penjualan, id_barang) {
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "index.php/transaksi/get_by_id/" + id_penjualan + "/" + id_barang,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
            $('[name="harga"]').val(data.harga_jual);
            $('[name="id_penjualan"]').val(data.id_penjualan);
            $('[name="id_barang_modal"]').val(data.id_barang);
            $('[name="nama_barang"]').val(data.nama_barang);
            $('[name="jumlah"]').val(data.jumlah);
            $('[name="sisa_stok"]').val(data.stok);
            current_stock = data.stok;
            $("#modal_detail").modal("show");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    })
}
```

and this is the validate function

```
 $("#form_detail").validate({
        rules: {
            jumlah: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                max: sisa_stok
            }
        },
        messages: {
            jumlah: {
                required: "Jumlah tidak boleh kosong.",
                number: "Jumlah hanya dapat diisi dengan angka."
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            save_edit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: How/when are you setting `current_stock`?

Comment: when click the Edit button, the Edit button also trigger the modal

Comment: Must be a scope issue. Post all the code refering to the modal and varible setting.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this line `max: current_stock`? Does the max change dynamically depending on the value of `current_stock`? If you're trying to validate the `current_stock` to make sure it is less than a max value, you need to provide the max value on that like, e.g. `max: 50`.

Comment: @muecas i edited the post with the code reference to modal and variable

Comment: @RacilHilan yes the max value change dynamically depending on the value of  `current_stock` . 
i tried to make user not to sell item greater than the exist stock. so the `max` need to be dynamically based on data from database.

Comment: you should not use max, use equalTo: "#current_stock"

Comment: @whoami do you mean like this : `max : $("#current_stock");` 
i did that too but it also doesnt work

Comment: use equalTo:$("#current_stock") instead of max:$("#current_stock");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that jQuery validator uses the variable value, and not its reference: at the moment of the validation initialization the value of `curent_stock` is 0, so that will be the value passed to the validator, and not a reference to the variable.

To achieve that, you should modify the field rule each time the ajax call has been completed, instead of:

```
current_stock = data.stok;
```

In your `success` function, change it to:

```
$('[name="jumlah"]').rules('add', {
    required: true,
    number: true,
    max: data.stok,
    messages: {
        required: "Jumlah tidak boleh kosong.",
        number: "Jumlah hanya dapat diisi dengan angka.",
        max: "Tidak bisa melebihi sisa Stok"
    },
});
```

Comment: @MochamadRamdannyLukman Great! Mark the answer as valid then. Thanks!

Comment: but can i write whole validate code in the ajax success? cause i getting trouble to set the message..

Comment: @MochamadRamdannyLukman getting trouble setting that specific field validation message? Let me edit my anwer.

Answer (score 0):

As muecas explained in his answer:

> The problem is that jQuery validator uses the variable value, and not
>   its reference: at the moment of the validation initialization the
>   value of `curent_stock` is 0, so that will be the value passed to the
>   validator, and not a reference to the variable.

However, you don't need to rewrite all the rules on the element to make it work. That's too much code redundancy and a violation of the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. All you need to do is update the `max` rule with the new value of `data.stok`:

In `$.ajax.success`, change this line:

```
current_stock = data.stok;
```

to:

```
$('#jumlah').rules('add', {
  max: data.stok
});
```

Unless you need it for something else, you don't need the variable `current_stock`. In your `$("#form_detail").validate`, simply give `max a static value:

```
max: 0
```